# Are success and failure listener methods done on a background thread?

Tags: java, android, google-places

Are methods using success and failure listeners done on the main UI thread, or a background thread?

For example, I'm using the [Google Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details). To fetch a place:

```
// Define a Place ID.
final String placeId = "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE";

// Specify the fields to return.
final List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

// Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
final FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);

placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
    Place place = response.getPlace();
    Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + place.getName());
}).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
        final ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
        Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
        final int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
        // TODO: Handle error with given status code.
    }
});
```

`fetchPlace()` is done in a background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I did some digging and here's what I came up with.

`placesClient.fetchPlace(...)` returns a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task):

[image: Task definition]

What that means for us right here is that you can hook it up to various listeners and get a ping whenever that state is hit. In your case with that specific `addOnSuccessListener(...)` method you picked, here's what the docs tell us:

[image: addOnSuccessListener(...) definition]

So basically, in your snippet the fetching will be done off the main thread, and then the results will be delivered back to the main thread.